# No repeating digits and reconstructing int

Tags: c++

The program i am designing is for an assignment, but as a do distant learning it is not easy finding a solution. 
The program that I have to create must first ask user for an unsigned long int and then break that number down to each digit without repeating number (for example 3344 the program should list 3 and 4), my program just lists all digits. After they have been listed the position of that digits needs to be dispayed with the position (digit at the right is position 0). Then the program should be "reconstruct" to make the original unsigned long int.

An example of what it should look like :

7377683

3 : 0 5

6 : 2

7 : 3 4 6

8 : 1

7377683

The code that i am using currently :

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;


 int main()
{
 unsigned long int number;

cout << "Enter an integer " << endl;
cin >> number;                            

for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++)

{
    if (number > 0)
    {
        cout << number%10 << " : " << i;   //output digit and position
        cout << "\n";                      
        number /= 10;                     

    }

 }

return 0;
}
```

I cannot use arrays or strings to complete this task and that is what i am finding challenging.

Comment: Maybe solve it first with an array or string, and then try to convert it to the other solution.

Comment: I have already done it for a string but have just started coding and seem to be having trouble getting my head round it

Comment: I know you are learning but I have to say problems like this are ridiculous. In what possible context would you want to do this without strings? By definition, the problem treats the number as a string else the recurrence of specific digits would be entirely irrelevant.

Comment: It's a useless problem for learning general app development. On the other hand, it is a stimulating intellectual challenge.

Comment: Yes i totally understand that is what has puzzled me, i starting writing the program using a sting but then in the breif it states only integers can be used :s

Comment: I don't know how you can reconstruct the original number if you hadn't stored something in arrays during the meantime.

Comment: When you say you can't use arrays, does that include static arrays? That would seem odd as for example `int x[10]` is pretty much a fancy way of saying `int x1, x2, ...`. So are you not allowed to use variables at all?

Comment: I have just looked at how they work it (i am studying in french so have to translate) and they say i can only use numeric variables so that does include arrays then ?

Comment: @NeilKirk I'd say CaptainObvlious answer provides a quite viable way.

Comment: The number that has to be reconstructed should be exactly the same as the one imputed. But when the int is read the first digit is position 0.

Comment: Is the number length limited to 10?

Comment: @DailyDoobie So you can use arrays of ints? That makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: They say only "numeric varaibles" not sure if that means arrays

Comment: I think I come out with a solution already... just that it is a little long.. DailyDoobie... hang on, let me type my answers.

Comment: I have just researched the meaning in french and basically we cannot use strings. So i should be able to use arrays (even though they are not mentioned in the book) but functions are touched up so maybe that is what they are looking for.

Comment: if you use array, it is too easy.. you may see my complete answer. The reconstruction, I leave it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store digit positions in a decimal bitmask type thing.

```
unsigned long n, digits[10]{};
// Input
std::cin >> n;
// Break down
for (int i = 1; n; i *= 10, n /= 10)
    digits[n % 10] += i;
// Reconstruct and print digit positions
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (!digits[i])
        continue;
    n += digits[i] * i;
    std::cout << i << ":";
    for (int j = 0; digits[i]; j++, digits[i] /= 10)
        if (digits[i] % 10)
            std::cout << " " << j;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
// Output
std::cout << n;
```

It's kinda neat because you don't need to know how many digits your number has. Also, you could construct the new number and output the positions of all digits in the same loop which you are breaking it down, thus removing the need to store the digits anywhere, but that feels like cheating.

Comment: This is a very good solution, it works perfectly I just have one question, at the end when you output the number are you simply just outputting the number they entered at the start or does the for loop help construct the number ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use arrays or strings you can probably get away with using an integral type as a bitmap. Any time you output a number in your loop set a bit in the bitmap that corresponds to that number. Then when you need to output that number you check to see if that bit is set and if it is you skip printing it out. Something like the following maybe.

```
for (int mask = 0, i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    if (number > 0)
    {
        int value = number % 10;
        if ((mask & (1 << value)) == 0)
        {
            cout << value << " : " << i << endl;   //output digit and position
            mask |= 1 << value;
        }
        number /= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better `unsigned int mask`?

Comment: Is this a complete solution? If it is, I dont't give my answer anymore.

Comment: I understand the concept behind the code, but there is no mention of bitmap in the book so not use it we can use this. I do not understand because this program is the first one i have to do, so should be very simple.

Comment: @DailyDoobie are you allowed to call functions?

Comment: Theoretically, you could use recursion, but it would be a horribly complicated solution, and definitely not a "beginner solution" either.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a number down into individual digits works like this:

```
int number = 4711;
vector<int> v;
while(number > 0)
{
   int digit = number % 10;
   number /= 10;
   v.push_back(digit);
}
```

Putting it back together again into an integer (we need to go "backwards", as the digits come out "back to front" in the above code)

```
int number = 0;
for(int i = v.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    number *= 10;
    number += v[i];
}
```

I'm intentionally not showing a complete program to solve your problem, since part of learning programming is to learn how to solve problems. But you sometimes need a few "steps" on the way.

Something like this would solve it with arrays:

```
int array[10][10] = { { 0 } };    // Position of each digit. 
int count[10] = { 0 };            // Number of each digit

int number = 4711;
int pos = 0;
while(number > 0)
{
   int digit = number % 10;
   number /= 10;
   count[digit]++;
   array[digit][count[digit]] = pos;
   pos++;
}
```

I'm leaving it to you to fill in the rest of the code (to print and reassemble the number). [The above code doesn't cope with the number zero].

Comment: _'I cannot use arrays or strings to complete this task'_ I'm not sure if this would invalidate use of `std::vector` also :-/

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I do not think that i need to use vectors as we haven't even learned arrays. Plus they say i can only use integers

Comment: Seems rather strange restrictions (and thus either you've misunderstood, or the course is unusually restrictive). Captain Oblivious have given a solution that solves this, but it uses bitfiddling, which seems like a very strange solution to use for such a problem (at least if you are at beginner level). Further, the answer you are showing in the question, which lists the positions for each digit would not be achievable by Captain Oblivius's method, since it only records "already seen", not "where it was seen".

Comment: Yes i also believe it to be weird thus why i posted it on the forum, They stated that I can only use "numeric variables" what does that mean ?

Comment: Who knows - "not strings", I suppose... But especially if you have translated from another language, "numeric variables" is not very clear if it means arrays of integers as well plain integers. But I can't really see a way to list the positions for each digit like your example does, wihtout using some sort of array.

Comment: True i think i will use an array for this, but with no real lesson to follow as it is not mentioned in the book. Would someone be able to hint me in the right direction

Comment: I have added a "two dimensional array" solution. I find this quite a complex "beginner task". Again, I'm not posting a complete solution, because you MUST learn to solve the problems yourself, or you won't really learn anything.

Comment: will arrays allow me to stop having repeated digits? and will it allow me to reconstruct the int at the end ?

Comment: I have nothing against learning and am willing to learn but as the question is so weird i kinda needed a push in the right direction :)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. With the data structure I describe above, you can reconstruct the number [but it's still non-trivial, but I can't really find any way to avoid that - it's a non-trivial problem in general]. Using `vector` would really only avoid the `count[digit]` part, since `vector` has a size in itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **working solution** which address to the most crucial problem in your question:

```
int number = 7377683;
int temp = number;
int pos = 0;
int counter = 0;
int currNum;
int uniqueCount = 0;
```

**Added**: Codes to check number of unique digits in number:

```
for (int x=0; x<9; x++)
    for (int y=temp; y>0; y/=10)
        if (y%10 == x)
        {
            uniqueCount ++;
            break; 
        }
```

Codes to generate the output of every unique elements and positions:

```
for (int y=0; y<uniqueCount; y++)
{
    pos = counter;
    currNum = number%10;
    cout << temp%10 << " : ";
    for (int x=temp; x>0; x/=10)
    {
        if (temp%10 == currNum)
            cout << pos << " ";

        pos++;
        temp /= 10;    
    }
    counter++;
    number /=10;
    temp = number;
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

**Program Output:**

```
3 : 0 5

8 : 1

6 : 2

7 : 3 4 6
```

This solution is using the most basic construct **without array** (according to your requirements).

Comment: This seems exactly the type of solution they are looking for as I have learned for loops and if statement.

Comment: @DailyDoobie, yes.. and you try running it. It works well. I just have to come out with another code using pure loop + ifs to find unique digits and it is more or less done.

Comment: Yes i have run the code it is good :) I am also trying to figure out a way to get unique digits but seems way to complex for a first program.

Comment: @DailyDoobie I have come out with the solution to check number of unique digits using pure baisc construct. If you like my answer, kindly "tick" my answer as your preferred solution =)

Comment: This code is working yet there are many things that seem not to not work and i have been trying to fix them. For example the first digit does not have position 0 and if i enter "555" for example I get 5: 1 2 and then 5: 3 what is weird